# How to navigate to a specific URLs inside a paragraph text in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to navigate to a specific URLs inside a Text. I am able to post the data from Textfield into MySQL Database using PHP. I successfully displayed this text as well. Sometimes this text may contain many URLs. I want to navigate to those URLs. I don't want to create separate TextFields for these URLs as the no. of URLs are not predictable.

**Example**

> Please go through the link to learn HTML http://www.w3schools.com/
>
> Please go through the link to learn great stuff
> https://www.youtube.com/
>
> for Flutter resources  https://flutter.dev/

All the above as a single message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the solution !

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify

```
dependencies:
  flutter_linkify: ^3.1.0
```

Basic:

```
import 'package:flutter_linkify/flutter_linkify.dart';

Linkify(
  onOpen: (link) => print("Clicked ${link.url}!"),
  text: "Made by https://cretezy.com",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to create hyperkinks in your text, For that using RichText can help you.

```
body: new Center(
          child: new RichText(
            text: new TextSpan(
              children: [
                new TextSpan(
                  text: 'Please go through the link to learn HTML ',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                new TextSpan(
                  text: 'http://www.w3schools.com/',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () { launch('https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/UrlLauncher-class.html');
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: He is saying that the no. of URL s are not predictable ! Your answer only works if he know the URL s !

Answer (score 0):

Use this package [Flutter_linkify](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify). It will handle hyperlinks in string.

Example

```
Linkify(
  onOpen: (link) async {
   //use flutter url_launcher package to open links in browser
    if (await canLaunch(link.url)) {
        await launch(link.url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $link';
      }
  },
  text: "Made by https://cretezy.com",
  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
  linkStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
);
```